# pam mount - my password prompt now says pam_mount password:

Tags: linux, pam, pam-mount

I am using pam_mount to mount users' home directory upon successfully logging into the system.  It works; however, the password prompt says:

pam_mount password:

Instead of just:

password:

How can I change it back to the original while keeping pam_mount?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `pam_mount` *below* `pam_unix` in the PAM stack.

Comment: Looks like that did it.

Answer (score 2):

From [`man pam_mount.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man5/pam_mount.conf.5.html):

> Name
>
> pam_mount.conf - Description of the pam_mount configuration file
>
> Overview
>
> The pam_mount configuration file defines soft defaults for commands pam_mount will be executing, the messages it will show, and which volumes to mount on login. Since pam_mount 0.18, the configuration file is written in XML so as to simplify the pam_mount code base while giving formatting freedom to the end-user. Special characters like <, > and & that are used by XML itself must be encoded as `&lt;`, `&gt`; and `&amp;`, respectively; additionally, " must be encoded as `&quot;` within a "" area, but these three/four symbols are unlikely to be seen often anyway.
>
> **. . .**
>
> Messages
>
> `<msg-authpw>pam_mount password:</msg-authpw>`
>   When pam_mount is not used with "use_first_pass" or "try_first_pass" keywords in the PAM configuration files (/etc/pam.d/), it will have to ask for a password. This is also the case if pam_mount is the first auth module in the block.  allows you to customize that prompt.
>
> `<msg-sessionpw>reenter...:</msg-sessionpw>`
>   In case the 'session' PAM block does not have the password (e.g. on su from root to user), it will ask again. This prompt can also be customized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found a single configuration file that did not have use_first_pass as an option for the auth part of the configuration.  None of my session configurations have use_first_pass or try_first_pass.  I will logout and login and see what happens.

Comment: That was a no go, odd that it complained.  I was missing that option in my system-auth configuration file.  I returned it back to what it was previously configured as.

Comment: The link is busted to the pam_mount.conf page you referenced.

Comment: @sim: I replaced the link.